# Examples of using Mathematica to solve matrix equations symbolically

Tags: matrix, symbolic, linear-algebra

Suppose we want to solve a linear system like

$$\left\lbrack\begin{array}{cc}M& S\\ -S^\mathrm{T}&0 \end{array} \right\rbrack \left\lbrack \begin{array}{c} x\\y\end{array}\right\rbrack = \left\lbrack\begin{array}{c} f\\g \end{array} \right\rbrack$$  for $x$ and $y$.  Where $M\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric positive definite, $S\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ is full rank and $x,y,f,g$ are all vectors of compatible size.  It is straightforward to find the solution of this system by hand as

$$y =(S^\mathrm{T} M^{-1} S)^{-1}(S^\mathrm{T} M^{-1} f + g)$$ 
\begin{align*}
  x=& M^{-1}(f-S y)\\
   =& (I- M^{-1}(S^\mathrm{T} M^{-1} S)^{-1} S^{\mathrm{T}})M^{-1}f\\
    &-M^{-1}(S^\mathrm{T} M^{-1} S)^{-1} g.
\end{align*}

Is there a way I can make Mathematica do this?  I ask because I would like closed forms of more complicated block matrix systems.

Comment: NCAlgebra might be what you are looking for — [see here](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/) .

Comment: @StephenLuttrell please, show an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NCAlgebra has been updated since I wrote my comment above in 2015. I have had a look at the current documentation at [NCAlgebra Documentation](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Encalg/DOCUMENTATION/index.html), and in the “Most Basic Commands” section there is NCMatrixDecompositions, and under that there are `NCUpperTriangularSolve` and `NCLowerTriangularSolve`. I have not actually tried these out myself, but their names strongly suggest that they would solve the above symbolic matrix equation.